# Regex to match anything after a delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, regex-lookarounds

I have the following case:

Time format and some description which is separated by a delimiter `-` (as like below)

`00:00 - Hello element`

I was using the below regex to detect the match

```
/((?:\d{2,}:)?(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)(\s?-.\w+))/g;
```

it matches only "00:00 - Hello" after space it's not getting match. Here is the demo of it https://regex101.com/r/omUEHy/1

Also, If the string matches multiple times in a same line it should work.

If I have text like as `00:50 - Hello element 01:50 - Poetry`. It should return `00:50 - Hello element` and `01:50 - Poetry`

Comment: `\w+` only matches one word. Use `.*` if you want to match the entire rest of the line.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, Yes, If I use .* it matches entire line. But, If the string repeats in the same line which matches the regex become normal text. I mean, If I have text like as `00:50 - Hello element 01:50 - Poetry` Based on my expectation it should match 2 strings (00:50 - Hello element and 01:50 - Poetry)

Comment: You could use `.*?` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: I have made the regex as like this as you suggested. 
`
((?:\d{2,}:)?(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)(\s?-).*?)
`
but it matches only `00:50 -` and `01:50 - ` after delimiter  whole text not matches. am I missing anything?

Comment: Yuo're right, that doesn't work. I think you have to use a negative lookahead to prevent matching a time in the `.*` portion.

Comment: Your regex for matching time is broken. 25:00 is not a valid time value here on Earth.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan 25:00 is a valid MM:SS time...

Comment: something like ... [`/\d{2}:\d{2}\s+.*?(?=\s+\d{2}:|\s+$)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/omUEHy/2)?

Answer (score 3):

The provided regex ... [`/\d{2}:\d{2}\s+.*?(?=\s+\d{2}:|\s+$)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/omUEHy/2) ... makes use of a [positive lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead) ... `(?=\s+\d{2}:|\s+$)` (either whitespace sequence double digit and colon or whitespace sequence and end of string) ... in order to define the termination of the lazy/non greedy match of any character ... `.*?` ... which does follow the opening matching sequence of ... `\d{2}:\d{2}\s+`.

```js
const multilineSample =
`00:50 - Hello element 01:50 - Poetry 00:50 - Hello element and another element    01:50 
- Poetry     00:50 - Hello element and another element    01:50 - Poetry  and prose 00:50 - Hello element   01:50   -   Poetry     `;

const regXTimeAndEntry = /\d{2}:\d{2}\s+.*?(?=\s+\d{2}:|\s+$)/g;

console.log(
  multilineSample.match(regXTimeAndEntry)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```